# Azure web app returns code 403 for 192.168* client IP

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, iis-10

I have an Azure Web app that runs Web API 2 and it provides an access to Azure blobs. I see from logs, that there are some user requests that are denied by the app with code 403 without even getting to the controller itself (there are no corresponding logs). The only special thing about those requests I remarked, is the client IP that has a pattern of 192.168.*.* I checked the block list of the app and it's empty. Has someone an idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you check the Web Server Logs:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/06/22/troubleshooting-azure-app-service-apps-using-web-server-logs/ for getting to the root cause of this issue along with Sub-Status.

Comment: Does your Web API support anonymous access? Or you have enabled some authentication settings? I would recommend you enable diagnostics logging for your web app to narrow this issue, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log). Moreover, you could try to compare the request headers between the normal request and the failed one to narrow this issue, maybe the authentication for the specific request is expired.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. When request passes through proxy (some of them maybe), its headers changes (the key case) and the comparison in the code is not working.